# How can I create a subset a database using multiple conditions?

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have a database such as this one:

[image]

And I need to create a smaller data frame that contains Colombia, Costa Rica, El Salvador, and Honduras (there are many other countries in the database), with the sub_region in column C empty, metro_area in column E empty, and with the data from columns L and M. Something like this:

[image]

I've tried the following:

```
COL <- subset(Basetotal, country_region == "Colombia" & sub_region_1 == "", select = c("date","transit_stations_percent_change_from_baseline"))
```

This with each country, but this is too slow. How can I more efficiently solve my problem with fewer lines of code?

Comment: Hi, I've updated my answer in response to your new edits. See below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
library(tidyverse)

Basetotal %>% 
  filter(
    sub_region_1 == "", 
    metro_area == ""
  ) %>% 
  pivot_wider(
    id_cols = date, 
    names_from = country_region, 
    values_from = c(
      transit_stations_percent_change_from_baseline, 
      workplaces_percent_change_from_baseline
    ) # spreads data from both columns L and M
  )
```

You can use `filter()` to subset your database using multiple conditions, and `pivot_wider()` to spread multiple country data across the table.